# Iteratively saving variables to files using Matlab save function

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am saving the contents of an array to different files as follows:

```
for i=1:10
name = [myfilename num2str(i)] 
savevar = myvariable(i)
filename = mat2str([name '.dat'])
save(filename, savevar, '-ascii','-double','-append')
end
```

I have been fiddling around with this for a while and keep getting the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> save
Argument must contain a string.
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arguments of the [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) command must be strings. Specifically, *the second argument* must be a string that contains the variable name.

The problem in your case is that `savevar` is the actual value of the variable, and not its name.

I'm not really getting what type of variable you're trying to save. If it's a matrix, you're just better off saving it as a whole to a single file, like so:

```
save(filename, 'myvariable', '-ascii', '-double', '-append')
```

and if you have numerous variables, and you want each variable in a different file (which is a bit closer to your example), I suggest you create a cell array of the variable names:

```
varname = {'A', 'B', 'C', ...}  % # Assuming A, B, C, etc. are actual variables
```

and then use it in the `save` command inside a loop:

```
save(filename, varname{i}, '-ascii', '-double', '-append')
```